# Ajustar logo en header

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Quiero hacer una cabecera que tenga el logo a la izquierda y luego poner tres líneas con:

- Nombre de la persona,
- Dato específico de la persona,
- Tres botones: teléfono, mail y whatsapp.

Pero tengo varios problemas:

1. Quiero que el logo se ajuste al alto de la cabecera y no lo hace.
2. El ancho del logo deberá auto-ajustarse según la altura del logo para mantener las proporciones.
3. No me centra los botones (no les he puesto estilo para no complicar el código)
4. Si estrecho mucho la pantalla, la segunda celda se superpone sobre el logo y lo corta

¿Alguien puede orientarme?

Os pego el código:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Times New Roman, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  /* Lo pongo =100% para que coja la letra por defecto del browser*/
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  /* Utilizo box-sizing para que los bordes me queden dentro de los elementos.*/
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: white !important;
}


/* No quiero que los link cambien de color ni queden subrayados */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: white !important;
  border-bottom: rgba(192, 32, 23, 1) solid 2px;
  display: table;
}

.header_logo {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: red solid 1px;
  margin: 0 0 0 2px;
}

.header img {
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 5px 0 2px;
}

.header_text {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: red solid 2px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<br>
<div class="header">
  <div class="header_logo">
    <img src="http://fangosto.com/apcs/web.png" />
  </div>
  <!-- header_logo -->
  <div class="header_text">
    <h1 style="color:black;text-decoration:bold;">JAVIER ANGOSTO nº 001</h1>
    <p style="color:grey;">Espediente nº 45.567</p>
    <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;text-align:middle;">
      <button onclick="location.href='/SCRN/ID=Main_Screen'">INIZIO</button>
      <button onclick="location.href='/SCRN/ID=Caldaia'">CALDAIA</button>
      <button onclick="location.href='/SCRN/ID=Filtraggio'">FILTRAGGIO</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- header_text -->
</div>
<!-- header -->
```

Comment: Algo he hecho mal al pegar el código. Podéis encontrar el código en el siguiente enlace http://fangosto.com/apcs/pruebas.html

Comment: no te apures ya lo edité y el código será visible en cuanto se apruebe la edición

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora se ve bien. Tengo que hacer el Tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para escalar la imagen debes jugar un poco con las proporciones, utiliza `width` como su valor inicial y después utilizas los `height` para definir los tamaños máximos y minimos:

```
.header img {
     max-height:100%;
     min-height:20%;
     width:50%;/*valor inicial*/
}
```

para centrar los botones debes forsozamente especificar el tamaño con `width` y despues solo ocupas `margin: 0 auto;` para un centrado perfecto:

```
<div style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 auto; width:100%;">
```

para evitar que los elementos se superpongan en diferentes tamaños de pantalla utiliza la etiqueta `<meta>` en el `<head>` para definir el `viewport` :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

#### Aquí la implementación

```css
* {  
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    border:0; 
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica,Verdana, Times New Roman, sans-serif; 
    font-size:100%; /* Lo pongo =100% para que coja la letra por defecto del browser*/
    text-align:center; 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    /* Utilizo box-sizing para que los bordes me queden dentro de los elementos.*/
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
} 
      
html,body{width:100%;height:100%;}

body{
    background-color:white !important;
}
 
a { 
    text-decoration:none;
}
    

.header{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
 height:15%; 
 background-color:white !important;
 border-bottom: rgba(192,32,23,1) solid 2px;
 display:table;
 }

.header_logo{
 display:table-cell;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align:middle;  
    border:red solid 1px;
    margin:0 0 0 2px;
}

.header img {
     max-height:100%;
     min-height:20%;
     width:50%;
}

.header_text{   
 display:table-cell;
 text-align:left;
 vertical-align:middle;    
    border:red solid 2px;
    font-size:2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header_logo">
     <img src="http://fangosto.com/apcs/web.png"/>
  </div><!-- header_logo --> 
  <div class="header_text">
    <h1 style="color:black;text-decoration:bold;">JAVIER ANGOSTO nº 001</h1>
    <p style="color:grey;">Espediente nº 45.567</p>
    <div style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 auto; width:100%;">
      <button onclick="location.href='/SCRN/ID=Main_Screen'">INIZIO</button>
      <button onclick="location.href='/SCRN/ID=Caldaia'">CALDAIA</button>
      <button onclick="location.href='/SCRN/ID=Filtraggio'">FILTRAGGIO</button>
    </div>    
  </div><!-- header_text -->
</div><!-- header -->
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Al final encontré la respuesta en internet, pero la tuya me ha matizado y mejorado lo que encontré.